Android 14 - Foreground service type for Activity Recognition
When targeting android 14, we should provide at least one foregroundServiceType for each service in manifest - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#fgs-types
Which foregroundServiceType should be used for ActivityRecognition?
Should I use "location" or "health"?
Here is my service:
<service
        android:name=".tracking.monitor.BackgroundDetectedActivitiesService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />


The documentation for the health type specifically mentions activity recognition, insofar as ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION is called out as a potential permission to satisfy requirements for this foreground service type. So, I would go with that.

You are right, thank you!
